# Представление чисел с плавающей точкой при вычислении координат точек

Tags: python, ооп, математика

Пишу программу, которая описывает геометрические примитивы в ООП стиле, в том числе и различные характеристики. Столкнулся с тем, что при описание класса прямая возникла такая ситуация: нахожу специальным методом точку пересечения двух прямых, потом, проверяя эту точку на принадлежность к любой прямой к которой она по идее приналдежит, метод, проверяющий это возвращает False, т.е. не приндлежность. Как я понял при выводе координат, все дело в каком-либо знаке после запятой. Суть вопроса: Как учитывать это при точных подсчетах? Какие варианты решения вообще существуют? Что можно почитать, что описывает точные математические подсчеты с точки зрения программирования?

Comment: не целые не константные числа нельзя сравнивать оператором равенства. Если вам нужно проверить являются ли эти числа +- одинаковыми, то вам нужна апроксимация. Установите, к примеру, процент погрешности и при сравнении проверяйте, находится ли второе число в диапазоне (певое_число+epsilon, второе_число-epsilon). Если да, то можно считать что числа равны, если нет - то нет

Comment: Можно проверять не точное попадание на прямую, а что расстояние от точки до прямой меньше какого-то (очень маленького) числа.

Comment: При работе с числами с плавающей запятой равенство обычно проверяется как `abs(a - b) < EPSILON`, где `EPSILON` - это величина допустимой погрешности. Для чисел типа `double` такая погрешность может быть порядка `1e-12`.

Comment: Для увеличения точности вы можете использовать встроенный класс `decimal`, но это обойдется вам в замедление скорости работы с числами.

Comment: Вам понадобятся рациональные числа. То есть пары целых. Целые должны быть не огранниченные - в геометрических расчётах быстро наступает переполнение. Это всё будет работать для отрезков и прямых.